# Show Icon at Right Side and Ellipsis Middle Text If Overflow In Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want two behavior.

1. [Working] If middle text is short, then heart icon should be next to middle text and cart should be at end,
   see image.

[image]

2. [Not working] If middle text is large, then heart icon should stick beside carts left and middle text be ellipsis.

[image]

Note: I have tried `Modifier.weight(1f,fill = false)` for second behaviour but then first broke.

**code**

```
 Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth()
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Search,"")

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(18.dp))

                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"")

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))

                Text(
                    text = "If text is long, then cart icon show at end with ellipsis text",
                    maxLines = 1,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f,fill = false)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(12.dp))

                Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite,"")
            }

            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.ShoppingCart,"")
            }
        }
```

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti updated the question, please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `Text` and the Favorite `Icon` with a `Row` and apply to it the `weight` modifier to fill the available space.
Then assign `weight(1f, fill = false)` to the `Text`:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Yellow),
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Search,"")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(18.dp))
        Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"")

        Row(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text(
                text = "If text is",
                maxLines = 1,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f, fill = false)
                    .padding(8.dp),
                overflow = TextOverflow . Ellipsis
            )
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.Favorite, "",
            )
        }

        Icon(Icons.Filled.ShoppingCart,"")
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You center component should use the "left space" with weight attribute

```
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .padding(8.dp),
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
```